Can I modify mechanical bar end shift levers such that they don't stop in the downward pointing lever position?
I like to build bikes with bar end shifters on moustache bar, looks neat, is cheap and pretty convenient.
However, with my current setup process, the left lever points straigth downwards in the small chainring position (with negligable cable tension) and only slighlty backwards on the big ring.

If I were to move the shifting process along the lever so that the shifting lever would point in a less peculiar direction, however, I would have the problem that I would not have a lower stop for the shifting lever. The upper stop to the chainring is controlled via the H limit screw on the derailleur, but the lower stop is not.
This is why I use the current funny looking lever setup, because I dont want the possibility of unneccessary cable slack when shifting down to the smaller chainring, especially if the bike is for a less experienced rider that does not internatilze the sound and feel of a finished shifting process as an indicator for the correct/minimum lever position.
Has anyone modified one of those Shimano friction shifters for the left side in such way that the lower stop becomes higher?
I believe that the underlying mechanism for these is pretty much the same among the majority of downtube and bar end friction shifter, in case someone has already a modded downtube lever

There is a lower stop on the front derailleur though.

You don't have to get into the guts of the mechanism if you really wanted to do this. You can just sand through the polish/ano and use epoxy to bond on a bit of aluminum, something like this to illustrate:


that is a proper idea, I'll give it a try sometime, thank you
